# "Display author and date information" displays date of creation instead of current revision (changed) date

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm working on Drupal 8 and I'd like to change the date shown on authoring info for the changed date instead of the creation date.

Comment: Back-end or front-end?

Answer (score 1):

In your node template (e.g. node.html.twig) you have the following:

```
<span{{ author_attributes }}>
  {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
</span>
```

`date` is the creation date. You can change it to:

```
{{ node.changedtime|format_date('long')  }}
```

Where `long` is the date format you want to print.